# Unable to assign items for grid 12 items and for list 8 items?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
layout: false,

  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.productsList.length;
    },
    paginatedItems() {
      return this.productsList.slice(
        this.currentPage * this.perPage,
        (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
      );
    },
  },

  methods: {
    layoutchange() {

      this.layout = !this.layout;

      if (this.layout === true) {

      } else {


      }
    },
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <!-- These two buttons switch the layout variable,
       which causes the correct UL to be shown. -->

  <a class="list-icon" v-bind:class="{ active: layout == false }" v-on:click="layoutchange"></a>
  <a class="grid-icon" v-bind:class="{ active: layout == true }" v-on:click="layoutchange"></a>
</div>

<ul v-if="layout == true">
  <div class="overflow-auto1">
    <div class="listview-plp" v-for="product in paginatedItems" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" </div>
    </div>
</ul>

<ul v-if="layout == false" class="grid-view">
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <div class="product-plp1" v-for="product in paginatedItems" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage">
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Unable to assign items for grid 12 items and for list 8 items. Don't know how to start with it.

But in ul tag i think i need to assign some condition, and pass it to the computed property In order to do that.

Can you please help me out in this. Thanks

Comment: In your code you use 10 for grid but in the title you say 12? What now?

Comment: Also please post the error that you are getting

Comment: Also in most of your code you use `this.layout` like a boolean, but in your computed object you use it as astring

Comment: @MrCodingB Sorry now i have corrected the code, Basically i am in a process of assigning items for grid 12 items and for list 8 items,  in the process i am struck at above logic and unable to place condition accordingly..

And this.layout is for grid and list toggling.

Comment: In this case you would just have to assign this.perPage to 12 and 8 accordingly. Inside layoutChange

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i assign that in layoutChange.  Basically i have written if else condition, But not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @MrCodingB Thanks it's perfectly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `this.perPage` in `layoutChange`:

```js
perPage: 12,
layout: false,
computed: {
  rows() {
    return this.productsList.length;
  },
  paginatedItems() {
    return this.productsList.slice(
      this.currentPage * this.perPage,
      (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
    );
  },
},
methods: {
  layoutchange() {
    this.layout = !this.layout;
    // If layout == true in grid-mode switch the numbers around
    this.perPage = this.layout ? 8 : 12;
  }
}
```